# SQL Server : generate a sequential number based on each condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL and trying to generate a number next to each condition it meets for each record it produces.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    [Account],
    [Account Name],
    generate #
FROM
    Supplier
WHERE
    Account Name IN ('JP', 'TC', 'KA')
```

So it would be something like this,

```
Account    Account Name      Generate #
---------------------------------------
T1000          JP                 1
T1001          TC                 2
T1033          KA                 3
T1039          KA                 4
```

So `Generate #` is what I'm trying to do in SQL Server.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "condition"?

Comment: you've got a top 10 without an order by. This will result in a random top 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select top 10 [Account], [Account Name],
       row_number() over (order by Account) as seqnum
from Supplier
where [Account Name] in ('JP','TC','KA')
```